# Why cant I copy a string from a file and register it to an object?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have to make a program to create a credit card and save values in a csv file. I also need to retrieve the data saved in order to use them in further program usage so I need to copy values like customerID, pin, amount of money from a cvs file. The values get copied as strings and I am using Integer.parseInt to convert them but it's giving me NULLPointerException

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreditCard {
    private static final double FEERATE = 0.03;
    private int Overdraft=500;
    private int initialValue;
    private int customerID;
    private int pin;

    public CreditCard(final int customerID,int initialValue) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
        this.initialValue = initialValue;
        this.pin = (int)(Math.random() * (99999 - 100)+100);
    }

    public int getCustomerID() {
        return this.customerID;
    }

    public int getInitialValue() {
        return this.initialValue;
    }

    public int getPin() {
        return this.pin;
    }

    public int getOverdraft() {
        return this.Overdraft;
    }

    public void debitAmount(int amount) {
        if(amount > getInitialValue()) {
            this.initialValue = 0;
            amount = getInitialValue() - amount;
            this.Overdraft = getOverdraft() - amount;
        }
        else {
            this.initialValue = this.initialValue - amount;
        }
    }

    public String showData() {
        return "Your PIN: "+getPin()+
                " Your amount: "+getInitialValue();
    }
}

public static CreditCard[] createArrayFromFile(CreditCard[] creditCard) throws IOException {
        String fileName="file.txt";
        File file=new File(fileName);

        BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String row;
        int i=0;
        while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = row.split(",");
            creditCard[i].customerID = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            creditCard[i].initialValue = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            creditCard[i].pin = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
            i++;
        }
        csvReader.close();

        return creditCard;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CreditCard[] creditCard = new CreditCard[50];
        createArrayFromFile(creditCard);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two problems: You never check the length of the `data` array. Presumably for some line of your file, `row.split(",")` is not returning the expected number of strings. Secondly, although this is not your current problem, parsing a CSV file (not CVS) by splitting on commas is not valid, since a CSV file can contain embedded commas and newlines inside double quotes (and embedded double quotes, escaped by doubling them). For this reason, you should always use a proper CSV library to parse CSV files.

Comment: Also, I am guessing you mean "customer" and not "costumer."

Answer (score 1):

Inside your parsing logic be sure to check that you are getting the correct data format. Never assume the data you parse will be correct. Protect your program from invalid input. Be sure to parse the input before creating your object to ensure you only create an object when parsing valid data.

```
while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] data = row.split(",");
    if(data.length == 3)
    {
       try
       {
          int customerID = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
          int initialValue = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
          int pin = Integer.parseInt(data[2]); //<-- create setter for pin
          creditCard[i] = new CreditCard(customerID, initialValue);
          i++;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
          System.out.println("Something went wrong parsing " + row);
       }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Size of split array returned invalid size of " + data.length);
}
```

Also be sure to add a setter for pin, otherwise you'll only be able to save the object to the file but when it comes time to retrieve the information from the file the pin will be reset by the constructor. Customers will be unable to get their money :(

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to initialize your object so that will not store your values to null. Change your code in while loop to this:

```
String[] data = row.split(",");
creditCard[i] = new CreditCard(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), Integer.parseInt(data[1]));

// creditCard[i].customerID = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
// creditCard[i].initialValue = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
creditCard[i].pin = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
System.out.println(creditCard[i].customerID + " " + creditCard[i].initialValue + " " + creditCard[i].pin);
i++;
```